# IN(Item, Set) in a calculated field dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i am trying to create a calculated field in a dataset where i need to use the experssion IN(item, set) to test if 'Covergate Type' field is equal to one of the below values:

```
Cargo
Contractors All Risks
Erection All Risks 
PI A&E Single Project
Single CGL
```

Ive tried to write:

```
IN(Coverage Type,"Cargo Contractors All Risks","Erection All Risks","PI A&E Single Project","Single CGL")
```

but it is not working.

Can any one help me how to write the syntax of `IN` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solve my problem by this calculated field formula from inside the dataset:

[image]

thank you for your support
Regards.
Georges

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIf` here with the various checks in a calculated field; there is no real `IN` equivalent in SSRS without custom code:

```
=IIf(Fields!CovergateType.Value = "Cargo"
    or Fields!CovergateType.Value = "Contractors All Risks"
    or Fields!CovergateType.Value = "Erection All Risks"
    or Fields!CovergateType.Value = "PI A&E Single Project"
    or Fields!CovergateType.Value = "Single CGL"
  , true
  , false)
```

Which will return a boolean value depending if it meets your requirement or not.

Change the field name/return expressions as appropriate for your requirements.

**Edit after comment**

You can definitely use this as a Calculated Field in a Dataset.

Say we have a simple query to generate a sample Dataset:

[image]

[image]

Now, add a Calculated Field with the expression above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This can then be used as a normal column anywhere in the report, or even in subsequent Calculated Fields in the Dataset:

[image]

[image]

Still not sure what you mean by the IN function in SSRS - I can't see anything in the [VB.NET function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1394ft8w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you supply a link I can amend the answer, but the first suggestion works fine as you can see.

Comment: your formula will work only if you create the calculated field outside the dataset. In my case i need to create it from the dataset and there is IN syntax there it is IN(Item, Set), but i donno how to illustrate the Set Part in my values.

Comment: Why do you say you can't use this in a Dataset? I've expanded my answer showing this in action.